# Pandas filtering one column but only if another column is less than a specified value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 |
| 25 | 8 |
| 67 | 4 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 67 | 0 |

And I'm trying to apply a filter that removes 0 values in C1 but only if the values in C2 are greater than two. At the moment my filter gives me an output that looks like this:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 |
| 25 | 8 |
| 67 | 4 |

whilst the output I want would be:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 |
| 25 | 8 |
| 67 | 4 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 67 | 0 |

my filter currently is:

`(df['C1'] != 0) & (df['C2'] > 2)`

but I've also tried

`(df['C1'] > 0) & (df['C2'] > 2)`

which gave me the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with two masks:

```
out = df[~(df['C1'].eq(0) & df['C2'].gt(2))]
```

Or:

```
out = df[df['C1'].ne(0) | df['C2'].le(2)]
```

Output:

```
    C1  C2
0  100  10
1   25   8
2   67   4
4    0   1
5   67   0
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [100, 25, 67, 0, 0, 67],
                   'C2': [10, 8, 4, 4, 1, 0]})
```

Comment: Those both still remove the row if either column matches the criteria, rather than only removing C1 values if C2 is less than 2

Comment: Are you sure you have numbers, not strings? What is the output of `df.to_dict()?`

Comment: They're all float64 (confirmed with df.dtype), and the filter is indeed discriminating betwee the values, it's just removing values where C2 is less than 2, even though C1 is greater than 0

Comment: @coghlan please provide a reproducible example, I updated my answer with one to demonstrate that it is indeed working.

Comment: I've since tested your solution multiple times and it works which means my issue is likely occuring elsewhere and not the filter anymore

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
new_df = df.loc[~((df.C1 == 0) & (df.C2 > 2))]
```

as should this one.

```
new_df = df.loc[(df.C1 =! 0) | (df.C2 <= 2))]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested, except using a different operator syntax.

Comment: @mozway Indeed, it is the same answer, but using `df.loc` and different operator syntax.